# Prove span is the smallest containing subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

In *Linear Algebra Done Right*, it proved that the span of a list of vectors in $V$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing all the vectors in the list.

I followed the proof that $span(v_1,...,v_m)$ is a subspace of $V$. But I don't follow the proof of smallest subspace.

Each $v_j$ is a linear combination of $v_1,...,v_m$ (to show this, set $a_j = 1$ and let the other $a$'s in $a_1v_1+...+a_mv_m$ equal $0$) [**I don't understand the sentence in the parenthesis. What is the message?**]. Thus $span(v_1,...v_m)$ contains each $v_j$.

Conversely, because subspaces are closed under scalar multiplication and addition, every subspace of $V$ containing each $v_j$ contains $span(v_1,...v_m)$ [**I don't understand this line**].

Thus $span(v_1,...v_m)$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing all vectors $v_1,...v_m$ [**how to reach this conclusion?**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) We wish to express $v_j$ as a linear combination of the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m$. So suppose
$$v_j = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_mv_m.$$
Then taking $a_j = 1$ and $a_i = 0$ for $i \neq j$ does the trick.

2) Recall that subspaces are closed under scalar multiplication and addition (its the definition). So if you take a subspace of $V$ containing ALL of $v_1, \dots, v_m$, then the subspace in question must also contain all linear combinations of $v_1, \dots, v_m$. That is, it contains their span.

3) We saw in 1) that the span contains all $v_j$. We saw in 2) that any subspace containing $v_j$ contains the span, so the span is indeed the smallest such subspace.

Answer (score 10):

Let $M$ be the smallest vector subspace of $V$ containing $v_1,\dotsc, v_n$. We claim that $M=\text{span}(v_1,\dotsc,v_n)$. Indeed, note that
$$
v_i=0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+\dotsb+1\cdot v_i+\dotsb+0\cdot v_n
$$
for all $1\leq i\leq n$. So by the definition of the span as the collection of all linear combinations of $v_1,\dotsc, v_n$, we have that
$$
v_i\in\text{span}(v_1,\dotsc, v_n)
$$
for all $1\leq i\leq n$. But $M$ is the smallest vector subspace containing $v_1,\dots, v_n$, so
$$
M\subseteq \text{span}(v_1,\dotsc, v_n).
$$
For the reverse inclusion, since $v_i\in M$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ and $M$ is a vector subspace (closed under addition and scalar multiplication) it follows that
$$
a_1v_1+\dotsb+a_nv_n\in M
$$
for all $(a_1,\dotsc, a_n)\in\mathbb{F}^n$ (i.e. $M$ contains all linear combinations of $v_1,\dotsc, v_n$). So
$$
\text{span}(v_1,\dotsc, v_n)\subseteq M.
$$

Comment: I like this a lot more because it actually shows the equality logic using the subset operator, as opposed to the original book's proof as well as the other answer. Thank you for elucidating this.

Comment: Also might want to add that the span of a set of vectors is always a subspace that contains the vectors. Then since $M$ was defined to be the smallest subspace containing $v_1,\dots, v_n $, and using the fact that $\text{span}(v_1,\dotsc, v_n)$ is a subspace containing the vectors $v_1,\dotsc, v_n$, we get $\{ v_1,\dotsc, v_n\} \subseteq M \subseteq \text{span}(v_1,\dotsc, v_n)$.